# Yii: ClassName and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getRandomPlayers"

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

i am facing a strange problem. i have a function defined in model which i have been using from weeks now, is suddenly giving me error

> ClassName and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getRandomPlayers"

following is my code:
**Model**

```
 public function getRandomPlayers($params)
{
    $criteria_obj= new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria_obj->order="random()";
    $criteria_obj->condition="user_id!=".$params['user_id'];
    $criteria_obj->limit=7;

    $random_users= Users::model()->findAll($criteria_obj);
    if(!empty($random_users))
        return $random_users;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function actionInviteRandom()
{
    $body_data = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
    $data_posted = json_decode($body_data);

    if(!empty($data_posted->user_id))
    {
        $check_valid_user=Users::model()->findByPk($data_posted->user_id);
        if(empty($check_valid_user))
        {
            $this->sendResponse(200, array("status_code" => "002",
                                                       "status_message" => Yii::t('strings', 'User does not exist'),
                                           )
                                );
        }
        else
        {
             $params=array(
                                "user_id"=>$data_posted->user_id,
                           );

            $get_users= Users::model()->getRandomPlayers($params);
            $count=0;
            if(!empty($get_users))
            {

                 die("here");
            }
         }

    }
}
```

please check. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: I am also unable to call other methods defined in the model.

Comment: You did actually add this function to the `Users` class right? Because you keep referring to `ClassName` and `Model`

Comment: yes actually it is Users calss

Comment: and you don't have any `model()` function overrides? i.e. if you do a `var_dump(Users::model())` it outputs a `Users` instance?

Comment: yes it does give a Users instance

Comment: Strange. The file & linenumber that are outputted, they match the piece of code you put here? As in: You aren't accidentally calling it from somewhere else as well? Because this is getting weirder by the minute :)

Comment: I think you have multiple classes with name "Users"!

Answer (score -1):

add static to functions name :

```
public static function getRandomPlayers($params){ ...
```

UPDATE:

then you can use it like :

```
 $get_users= Users::getRandomPlayers($params);
```

Comment: I get this
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelName::getRandomPlayers()

Comment: yes, called the same way. see my previous comment. did not work